# Load Balancer Health Check and ECS Capacity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am pretty confused on how does auto scaling works with Capacity provider, i do know it creates a target tracking scaling policy in cloud watch which tracks the utilization of  instances , but what happens when a Load Balancer health Check fails. Below is our infrastructure 
ECS Cluster 
ECS Service
ECS Task
ELB
Target Group
ASG(EC2)
We have Target group associated with ELB ( but we have not associated ASG with target group), we are using capacity provider and turned on Managed scaling .
What would be behavior incase of Load Balancer health check failure, how does capacity provider track this health check

Comment: capacity provider is not related to your ALB's health checks.

Comment: so what's the behavior in ELB health check failure, does new ec2 instance get created ?

Comment: No. CP has nothing to do with the health of your instances. If a tasks fails, ECS services spins new task in its place.

Comment: so health check of ELB has no value ?

Comment: You are confusing capacity providers with ecs services. Please check aws docks to read about them.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I am now able to differentiate between ECS Autoscaling , EC2 AutoScaling and Capacity Provider. The only doubt is , CP provider uses Autoscaling , we can  associate Autoscaling with ELB , we can enable ELB health check with AutoScaling. If health check of ELB fails what would happen in this case ?